# Space this evenly according to the circles, ignoring the space taken up by the text

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-layout

I have this widge in flutter

I am using a Progress Bar because eventually there will be progress, this is an example

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double containersWidth = 510;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: containersWidth,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 14.0,
            width: containersWidth,
            child: LinearProgressIndicator(
              value: 0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
              minHeight: 3,
              valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.redAccent),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: containersWidth,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                _Circle(),
                _Circle(),
                _Circle(),
                _Circle(),
                _Circle(),
                _Circle(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _Circle extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Circle({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 30.0,
          height: 30.0,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.amberAccent,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This produces a layout like this one, which is fine

[image: layout without text]

Now, I need to add a label under each circle, but keep the space the same as the image, but when I do this,

```
class _Circle extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Circle({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 30.0,
          height: 30.0,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.amberAccent,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
        ),
        Text('example')
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

the width of the container increases, and since the space is counted from the center of the container, I obtain something like this

[image: no good]

I need the circles placed as in the first image, and the labels under the circles, centered, but not being counted as part of the width of the container.

I tried to used Positioned to wrap the labels but it didn't work because the overflow is hidden and also I was not able to position the text centered from the circle. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:

this is how it looks when using Positioned

[image: positioned]

with the following code

```
class _Circle extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Circle({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 30.0,
          height: 30.0,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.amberAccent,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 14,
            child: Text('example')
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The overflow is hidden, and besides, I don' know how to center the text relative to the Stack ( and the circle)

I am thinking I have to use SizedOverflow box, I will see if I can figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it like this

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  final double containersWidth = 510;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 30,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: containersWidth,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0),
      child: Stack(
        //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          LinearProgressIndicator(
            value: 0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
            minHeight: 3,
            valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.yellowAccent),
          ),
          Container(
            // color: Colors.redAccent.withAlpha(100),
            width: containersWidth,
            child:  Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                _Circle(),
                _Circle(),
                _Circle(),
                _Circle(),
                _Circle(),
                _Circle(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _Circle extends StatelessWidget {    
  const _Circle({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedOverflowBox(
      size: Size(30, 47.3),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 30.0,
            height: 30.0,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.yellowAccent,
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 4.3,),
          Text("example"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If there is something wrong with my code, please let me know

This is the result

[image: result]